# Dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu questions and concerns

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, partitioning, boot-repair

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows 10. Initially after installation I have errors with grub, but after trying different solutions, it worked on startup however the option for Windows called `Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)` did not work and simply refreshed the grub again.

After looking around I used the Boot-Repair tool to fix this and a second Windows loader called `Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)` appeared which successfully loading Windows.

I have some questions about my installation:

1. Does it matter that the first Windows loader does not work, why does it not work, and is there anything further I need to do?
2. Why does it not say *Windows Boot Manager* as it does in the examples I have seen?

   *I still want Windows to be the main operating system I use and therefore:*
3. Which partitions are Windows 10 and Ubuntu on and how can I tell this?
4. Is Windows 10 still located on the larger (465 GB) partition as I want it to be?
5. Is Windows 10 still the 'main' or 'host' operating system if that if is something that exists?

**GRUB boot menu**

```
 Ubuntu
*Advanced Options for Ubuntu
 Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
 Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)
```

Here are the results of `df` in the Ubuntu terminal:

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks   Used Available Use%   Mounted on
udev             4036064       0  4036064    0%   /dev
tmpfs             811072    9748   801324    2%   /run
/dev/sda6       12319664 4562768  7108040   40%   /
tmpfs            4055348     220  4055128    1%   /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4     5116    1%   /run/lock
tmpfs            4055348       0  4055348    0%   /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             811072       4   811028    1%   /run/user/1000
```

relevant `fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0cf3f5fa

Device  Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048    1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  *    1026048  958269439 957243392 456.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       958271486 1000214527  41943042  20G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       983570432 1000214527  16644096  8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       958271488  983570431  25298944  12.1G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: The info in the terminal is the best for analysis.  It also make it easier indexed in the search engines for identify similar problems and questions.  Will you give the output of: `sudo fdisk -l`.  The first bunch of lines that are referring to ram disk (`/dev/ram*`) isn't neccesary.  Just the ones below those.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Only the partition that is marked as Boot in Windows Disk Management can be really booted. In your case, it’s the second partition on the disk, so marked as `/dev/sda2` in Linux.
2. What examples? I have seen `Windows <version> (loader)` every time. Maybe it differs between Ubuntu versions?
3. The partitions:

   1. `/dev/sda1` or `D:` is system reserved by Windows. You should not touch it until you exactly know what you are doing.
   2. `/dev/sda2` or `C:` is the main Windows partition.
   3. `/dev/sda6` is the Ubuntu [root partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#Root_partition_.28always_required.29).
   4. `/dev/sda5` is probably the Ubuntu [swap partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#Swap_.28very_recommended.29).
4. Yes, it is.
5. The operating systems are equivalent. However, one system must tell the computer how to boot – a bootloader. Currently your bootloader is Grub and it is the recommended way of dual-booting Windows and Linux.

Comment: Great thanks. I thinkg have added the fdisk -1 output to my original question albeit not neatly.

Comment: @Robbie It’s `-l` – lowercase `L`, not `1`.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Boot loader:**

The boot loader is a partition managed with Windows Data on it.  One of them is a 500 meg partition.  This is not enough space for a real OS installation.  It's most likely a reserved partition with the default Windows installation files.  It could be used for a factory restore of Windows.

**2. Why does it not say `windows boot manager`?**

Windows Boot loader is an UEFI naming of the discovered partitions with the Windows boot files.

**3. Which partition is Windows and Ubuntu installed?**

Ubuntu is installed on partition `/dev/sda6`.  Windows is installed on `/dev/sda2`.

**4. Is Windows 10 still located on the lager (465 GB) partition?**

Your windows partition would not have been effected by the Ubuntu Installation on a separate partition.  So, yes.  It's exactly the way it was before the Ubuntu installation.

**5. Is Windows 10 still the `main` or `host` operating system if that exist?**

That doesn't exist in this and a normal case.  Neither OS is hosting the other.  You have the option of which one to boot.  Booting to either Windows or Ubuntu is independent of each other.  The actual boot process is determined by your boot manager.  The boot manager you are using is `UEFI`.  This was developed by Intel and has been used on the recent Microsoft shipped Computers.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, really helpful. I am correct in thinking the dual boot of windows 10 and ubuntu is now successfully installed?

Comment: The command is a lower case `L` (`l`).  You typed in a number `1` which is producing errors.  Can you try the command again.  And by the way, I figured out your Windows partition by your `GRUB boot menu` output in your original post.  I updated my answer to include that Windows is installed on `/dev/sda2`.  And yes.  I don't blame you for being concerned about your precious data and it's location.

Comment: @Robbie You can format your output by highlighting what you want formatted.  Then click on the format markdown tool which is the open and closed braces: **`{}`**.

Comment: Ah -l, I have now updated the output to sudo fdisk -l

Comment: From your current output it turns out that you have allocated a large amount of space for your swap and a very small amount of space for your Linux installed.  You will be out of space on Linux soon.   I would recommend that you boot to your live disk and resize your `ext4` and `swap` partitions.  Make the swap partition about 1.5 times the amount of ram you have.  If you have 8Gigs of ram, make your swap about 12gigs.  The other space can be allocated for Linux.

Comment: is this the correct way to do that? Boot to a LiveCD or LiveUSB drive in "try me" mode.
Load gparted (should be installed by default, you can apt-get it if it's not)
Resize your partitions (right click, click resize, follow the instructions).
Click apply and sit back while it does the job.
Reboot, taking out the USB stick or CD when it tells you to.

Comment: Yes... exactly.

Comment: On GParted how do I let it increase my partition size? currently the maximum it lets me extend the swap section to is 8127 MiB

Comment: Okay.  Rechecking your output, it's set correctly.  You don't have to change anything.  I noticed the 12 Gigs for Linux, and inferred there were most somewhere.  However, there isn't.  When you run out of hard drive space on Linux you will either have to install a second hard drive, or use gparted to split your Windows partition.

Comment: Pleasure!  Enjoy `Ubuntu`!